# Retrieve Total Chapters in each books

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have got the database which has `id`,`chapter_name`,`chapter_num`,`verse_num`,`verse_text`,`testament` as columns.

I would like to retrieve chapterName and the total number of chapters in each book.

I'm using the following query to do so,

```
select chapter_name, count(chapter_name) from TABLE_NAME group by chapter_num;
```

Unfortunately, it lists a very big count of chapter names and duplicate chapter names as well. How can I fix this?
This is the sample input

`id`,`chapter_name`,`chapter_num`,`verse_num`,`verse_text`,`testament`

```
 1,   "Genesis",    1,             1,       "text",      0
 1,   "Genesis",    1,             2,       "text",      0
 1,   "Genesis",    1,             3,       "text",      0
 .
 .
 .
 1,   "Revelation",   1,             1,       "text",    0
```

The output should be,

```
  `id`, `chapter_name`,`count(chapter_name)`



   1,       'Genesis',       50
   2,        'Exodus'        40
   .
   .

   66       'Revalation '    21
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @TheImpaler Please check this https://github.com/godlytalias/Bible-Database/blob/master/English/holybible.db

Comment: I'm using similar database with modified column names

Comment: The sample data must be short, representative. Not a whole database.

Comment: I want the query that returns chapter names in a column and another column that returns the total count of chapters in each chapter.

Comment: Do you mean book names and the total number of chapters in each book?

Comment: I asked if you want the book names and the number of chapters of each book and you replied yes. Then you edited and provided different sample data and only chapters. You also provided a link for a database that includes only 1 table which is not the table with your sample data. Do you want a solution? Clarify.

Comment: @forpas i provided the same output. Bookname and the number of chapters in each book. Please see the last portion of my update :)

Comment: No this is not book names and the number of chapters in each book. This is **chapter names** and the number of what?

Comment: I want to get an output that says ''Genesis" has 50 chapters, Exodus has 40 chapters so on and so forth @forpas

Comment: I your sample data Genesis is a chapter under the column `chapter_name`. Does this chapter has subchapters?

Comment: @forpas they have subverses indicated by `versenum`

Comment: So finally do you want for each chapter the number of verses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a table of verses with redundant chapter (chapter_num) and book (chapter_name) information. We must first eliminate the redundancy and get a single row for each book and chapter. Then we can count them.

```
select
  chapter_name,
  count(chapter_num)
from (
  select
    chapter_name,
    chapter_num
  from verses
  group by chapter_name, chapter_num
)
group by chapter_name;
```

Redundancy indicates a poorly designed schema. There's three pieces of information, so there should be three tables: book, chapter, verse.

```
create table books (
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table chapters (
  id integer primary key,
  num integer not null,
  book_id integer not null references books(id),

  unique(book_id, num)
);

create table verses (
  id integer primary key,
  num integer not null,
  content text not null,
  chapter_id integer not null references chapters(id),

  unique(chapter_id, num)
);
```

Now if we want to find how many chapters are in each book...

```
select
  books.name, count(chapters.id)
from books
join chapters on chapters.book_id = books.id
group by books.id
```

Or how many verses are in each book...

```
select
  books.name, count(verses.id)
from books
join chapters on chapters.book_id = books.id
join verses on verses.chapter_id = chapters.id
group by books.id
```

[Try it out](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4d63ce5acf5949b16da8dea3bc59e499).